# facebook post article with user token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello i'm trying to post on a user's wall a big foto article like this one

[image]

I have tried this code

```
$post =  array(
                'access_token' => $row['user_token'],
                'message' => 'Hello world ',
                'link' => $row['url'],
                //'name'          =>  "This is my title",
                //'caption'       =>  "My Caption",
                //'description'   =>  "Some Description...",
                'picture'       =>  $imgurl
                //'image' => $row['img']
        );

    $res = $facebook->api("/" . $row['facebook_id']. "/feed", 'POST', $post);
```

and it produces a small picture like this one
[image]

And this code produces nothing

```
/* make the API call */
$response = $facebook->api(
    "/me/objects/article",//or /$user_id/objects/article
    "POST",
    array (
        'fb:app_id' => '302184056577324',//change with stuff
        'og:type' => 'article',
        'og:url' => 'Put your own URL to the object here',
        'og:title' => 'Sample Article',
        'og:image' => 'https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png',
    )
);
/* handle the result */
```

Can someone provide working code or explain like you would to a 7 years old ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content#images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image to be displayed at the larger size, the source image has to be at least 1200x630px as described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content#images and already pointed out by CBroe...

Comment: i used an 1600px × 1200px image and it still shows up small and to the left

Comment: i had to look in facebook news, cose in my facebook wall all pics are small, while in news they are big